# How get DB data other than Grid data while editing jqGrid rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

i want edit jqGrid row data. while editing i want to show Data Base data in the edit popup instead of grid data. is it possible?
example:
Data base values: Jan=20,Feb=19,Mar=20 etc.
after doing some logic data showing in the Grid: Jan=13540,Feb=13500,Mar=13540 etc.
while editing data in edit popup showing Grid values but i want show DB values.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No idea how to proceed. :( i have less knowledge on JqGrid

Comment: Got the solution, use 'beforeShowForm' attribute of the jqgrid and call ajax call to the controller action and assign the values to the grid edit form

Comment: 'beforeShowForm: function (formid){var id = localStorage.getItem('EstimatesId');$.ajax({url: "/ControllerName/ActionName?id=" + id,type: 'GET',dataType: 'json',cache: false,data: { 'id': id },success: function (results) {$('#Jan').val(results[0]); $('#Feb').val(results[1]); $('#Mar').val(results[2]); $('#Apr').val(results[3]); $('#May').val(results[4]); $('#Jun').val(results[5]); $('#Jul').val(results[6]); $('#Aug').val(results[7]); $('#Sep').val(results[8]);$('#Oct').val(results[9]); $('#Nov').val(results[10]); $('#Dec').val(results[11]); },error: function () {alert('Error occured'); }});}'